# Complex regular expression for validate phone number based on state prefix

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm writing, or at least trying, a regular expression for validate Venezuela phone numbers in Javascript. I made a basic expression: `/^0[0-9]{10}$/` which allow numbers like for example:

```
02129876543 (VALID)
02139876543 (INVALID)
02149876543 (INVALID)
```

But 2nd and 3th are not valid since the prefix values `213` and `214` are not valid. I have a list of valid prefixes (taken from Wikipedia) and is this one:

```
248, 281, 282, 283, 235, 247, 278, 243, 244, 245, 246, 273, 278, 235, 285, 286, 288, 
241, 242, 243, 245, 249, 258, 287, 212, 259, 268, 269, 237, 235, 238, 246, 247, 251, 
252, 253, 271, 273, 274, 275, 212, 234, 239, 287, 291, 292, 295, 255, 256, 257, 293, 
294, 276, 277, 271, 272, 212, 251, 253, 254, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 271, 
275, 260, 270, 412, 414, 424, 416, 426
```

How I can build a regular expression for check validity of these prefixes? A valid number should start **always** with zero `(0)` followed by any of the prefixes above, followed by seven digits, can any give me some help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex will be a long one to include all these prefixes but you can build something on this alternation pattern:

```
/^0(?:212|24[123589]|252|294)[0-9]{7}$/
```

Comment: So, if I get it, I should add any prefix to the regex? Right?

Comment: while the answer is correct, it seems like you have forgotten some prefixes, like `281`, `271`, `426`... is that normal ?

Comment: @pomeh is not  right at all but is just an example to put me in the right path and I get it, so points to anubhava, I like more the second approach

Comment: @pomeh No I didn't build whole regex for OP, just gave an example on how to build the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Building on to @anubhava's answer, you would build it out for each. The overall regex would look like this..

```
^0(?:2(?:12|3[45789]|[45][1-9]|6[0-9]|7[0-8]|8[1235678]|9[1-5])|4(?:1[246]|2[46]))\d{7}$
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kY7gN9/2)

Answer (score 1):

And the complete regex would be,

```
^0(?:2(?:12|4[1-9]|5[1-9]|6[0-9]|7[0-8]|8[1-35-8]|9[1-5]|3[45789])|4(?:1[246]|2[46]))\d{7}$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eM2yY0/4)